# website legitimate or not, how to evaluate?

Tags: websites

how to know which website is secure to open ? i.e.

https://cdn.redhat.com/

why am I getting a security notification even when the site relates to Redhat ?

Thanks

Comment: At a minimum you should include details of what the security notification is saying.

Comment: Can you specify the browser you are using ? and please try to explain more of the issue or maybe a screenshot of the message.

Comment: This site is not secure

This might mean that someone’s trying to fool you or steal any info you send to the server. You should close this site immediately.


Details

Your PC doesn’t trust this website’s security certificate.
Error Code: DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA
Go on to the webpage (Not recommended)

Comment: used firefox, Microsoft IE and Edge. with all of them its same certificate related error.

Comment: Thanks for responding (many don't :-). However, at least for future questions, please [edit] the question when adding extra details (it's harder to read in comments, and they may disappear).

Answer (score 1):

> why am I getting a security notification even when the site relates to Redhat ?

Because it uses a certificate that is not trusted by your browser (or OS).

[image: Site certificate authority]

This appears to be an CA used by Red Hat, for instance for https://subscription.rhn.redhat.com/ as well. The common thing for these sites are that they are mainly useful if you're running Red Hat. I suspect that they include this CA in RHEL, allowing verification of the certificates by the sites.

Furthermore, those sites do request a client certificate for authentication:

```
$ openssl s_client -port 443 -host cdn.redhat.com
[...]
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=US/ST=North Carolina/O=Red Hat, Inc./OU=Red Hat Network/CN=Red Hat Entitlement Operations Authority/emailAddress=ca-support@redhat.com
/C=US/ST=North Carolina/L=Raleigh/O=Red Hat, Inc./OU=Red Hat Network/CN=Entitlement Master CA/emailAddress=ca-support@redhat.com
/C=US/ST=North Carolina/O=Red Hat, Inc./OU=Red Hat Network/CN=Red Hat Candlepin Authority/emailAddress=ca-support@redhat.com
[...]
```

This indicates that their CA issues certificates that clients uses to authenticate against Red Hat's servers. This requires that they control the CA.

Getting the CA into the roots of browsers is probably not worth-while as clients will not have any business on these sites, unless they have a client certificate. If they have a client certificate, installing the root certificate as well is trivial, if it's not included in RHEL by default.

---

Edit: This is likely wrong
This would somewhat improve security from Red Hat's point of view: they don't have to rely on external parties for securing their own infrastructure. They can peg the update clients to that single CA, which they fully control. If this is done, it would stop any other CA to act as MiTM.

---

When it comes to evaluating security, the steps I did to check was the following:

- Verify that it's really redhat.com, and not some similar name with e.g. Cyrillic characters.
- Check certificates OU and Common Name. I googled these two, which gave me [this article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/189533) from RedHat, which indeed verifies that they use these OU's and CN's.